# Color Row if Date in column = Sysdate in SharePoint Foundation 2013 using CSR

Tags: javascript, client-side-rendering

I´m using a List with about 400 Rows, for each day one.
Now i want to color each row where the Date is a Day of Weekend (Sat & Sun). This Part is wokring fine with this JS

```
var statusColors =  {
'Samstag' : '#B2B2B2',  
'Sonntag' : '#B2B2B2',
     };

   var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
   for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
   {
      var status = rows[i]["Spalte2"];
      var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
      var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
      row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
```

now, i want to check my Date Column against Today to color the row tih todays date. But with this version nothing is colored now.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
 OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

var statusColors={
'Samstag' : '#B2B2B2',  
'Sonntag' : '#B2B2B2',
'Today'  :'lightgreen'
};

for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
  var status=rows[i]["Spalte2"]; //internal Column name for my Name of the Day
  var date = rows[i]["Spalte3"]; //internal Column name of Date in Format dd.mm.yyyy
  if(GetDaysAfterToday(date)===0){
     status='Today';
  }
  var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
  var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
  row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
}
 }
}); 
});
```

Any Ideas where the Problem could be?

Comment: What does ``document.write(today) : '#FFFF00'`` do? And you also need to checkout standard SharePoint function ``GetDaysAfterToday()``

Comment: What is the name of the column that contains the date that you need to compare today's date with? Is it called `Spalte3`? Does this column return a date? (I note your 'Status' column returns the day, Monday, Tuesday, etc.) Try doing `console.log(status)` after `var status = rows[i]["Spalte3"];`. Check your browser's console for the output. Then you will know what you need to check against.

Comment: @Submits Yes. my Date is in the internal column called "Spalte3" with the format of dd.mm.yy. The Day (Monday, Tuesday, ..) is in column "Spalte2"

Comment: I haven't used `GetDaysAfterToday` before but my guess is it expects a JavaScript `Date` object but your `date` variable is giving it a `string`? Try creating a new JavaScript `Date` object with the dd mm and yyyy values and pass this to `GetDaysAfterToday`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var statusColors={
    'Saturday' : '#FFF1AD',  
    'Sunday' : '#FFF1AD',
    'Today'  :'lightgreen'
};
```

and

```
for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
      var status=rows[i]["Status"];
      var date = rows[i]["Spalte3"];
      if(GetDaysAfterToday(date)===0){
         status='Today';
      }
      var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
      var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
      row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
   }
```

#### Update #1

You copy pasted the above code without looking at it.. it is missing one line.

I think your logic can be done simpler, without a SharePoint field for the daynames:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
    OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
      ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function(row){
        var id = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, row),
            date=new Date(row.DueDate),//" " notation not required in 99% of the code
            days=GetDaysAfterToday(date),//SharePoints today function, negative for past days
            daynr=date.getDay(),//sunday=0, saturday=6
            color=['black','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','red'][ day ];
        if(days===0) color='yellow';
        console.info(date,daynr,color,days);
        document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color;
    });
  } 
});
```

PS. Since you missed that one line I can tell you do not know how to debug JavaScript.

Go use Google and learn all about the F12 Developer console, tracing with `console.log` and his whole family of console friends and the `debugger` statement.

That will save you heaps of time in your copy/paste career

PS2: I purposely left one bug in the above code

Comment: @DannyEngelmann Thank you. But with this Code the Today and also the Weekend didn´t work. But i found a mistake by me. I don´t have the Status Column (it´s a copy issue from me)

Comment: i´ve updated the Start Post with my actual Code by your help but  it isn´t wokring.